# link_to :remote => :true fails in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, html, prototype

I'm having a problem with remote links in IE, and I need to get it up & running soon cause the deadline is today :S
The problem is that we're using AJAX to make a remote call to an action and eval the returned javascript.

When making the call using Firefox for example it's working fine, if I do it in IE, the response is made as HTML request.

**IE entry in development log**

> Started GET "/semantic/country/5" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Sep 07 12:06:00
>   +0200 2011   Processing by Semantic::SemanticController#country as HTML 
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}   Country Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.*
>   FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1 Rendered
>   semantic/semantic/country.js.erb (1.0ms) Completed 200 OK in 1785ms
>   (Views: 54.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

**Firefox call in development log**

> Started GET "/semantic/country/5" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Sep 07 12:06:00
>   +0200 2011   Processing by Semantic::SemanticController#country as JS 
>   Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}   Country Load (1.0ms)  SELECT `countries`.*
>   FROM `countries` WHERE `countries`.`id` = 5 LIMIT 1 Rendered
>   semantic/semantic/country.js.erb (1.0ms) Completed 200 OK in 1785ms
>   (Views: 54.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)

The code used to generate the link is the following (in HAML):

```
link_to @vacancy.country.name, semantic_country_url(@vacancy.country.id), {:remote => true, :class => 'ajax'}
```

The problem seems to be how IE interprets the data-remote stuff in the HTML5. Is there a solution around this?

**without switching to jquery**, beause I cannot rewrite all the javascript in the application.

**EDIT**
Found out that the IE browser sends the request twice now,first time a JS, which  works fine, but second time as HTML.

Comment: How does the code in your controller action look like? Because I seem to remember one time when I had some similar problem and the reason seemed to be the order in which I used the formats in my respond_to block. I think I solved it by putting the `format.html` block before the `format.js` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't run firebug AND IEdevtools at the same time...They both respond to the feedback messages and start acting weird in this case.
Once I shut down Firebug IE worked fine.